# Formatting RestSharp request for ESRI geocoder

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp, esri

I have some code that formats a JSON request using RestSharp to access ESRI geocoding API. The code works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to get the request into the correct format here is a sample of what I have and below a sample of what the request should look like.

```
request = new RestRequest("geocodeAddresses", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //Format the request properly
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        attributes.Add("OBJECTID", address.Address);
        attributes.Add("Address", address.Address);
        attributes.Add("City", address.City);
        attributes.Add("Region", address.State);
        attributes.Add("Postal", address.ZipCode);

        JsonObject attributesObj = new JsonObject();
        foreach (var parms in attributes)
        {
            attributesObj.Add(parms);
        }


        JsonObject recordsObj = new JsonObject();
        recordsObj.Add("attributes", attributesObj);
        JsonArray EsriRequest = new JsonArray();
        EsriRequest.Add(recordsObj);
        JsonObject addressObj = new JsonObject();
        addressObj.Add("records", EsriRequest);




        request.AddParameter("addresses",
            addressObj.ToString());
        request.AddParameter("token", esriToken.ToString());
        request.AddParameter("f", "json");
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
        IRestResponse<EsriAddress> responseData = client.Execute<EsriAddress>(request);
```

Request output sample:

```
http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?addresses={"records":[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":1,"Address":"380 New York St.","City":"Redlands","Region":"CA","Postal":"92373"}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":2,"Address":"1 World Way","City":"Los Angeles","Region":"CA","Postal":"90045"}}]}&sourceCountry=USA&token=<YOUR TOKEN>&f=pjson
```

I currently only ever send one address, but in theory the api can take more then one at a time.

Comment: Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I send a batch of addresses to the geocodeAddresses method in the [ArcGIS REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-geocode-addresses.htm).  I'm not using RestSharp, just [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```cs
string token = GetToken();
string url = "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses"; 

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var values = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", token),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("forStorage", "true"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxBatchSize", "1000"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("outFields", "*"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("f", "json"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("addresses", inputJson)  // json string containing an array of a complex type
        };

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)        
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        Task<string> responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string outputJson = await responseString; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going back through this project and I think this is the correct answer, but do you know if using this batch method cost credits?

Comment: For anyone else that needs this, this works. Not sure yet if it cost credits or not.

Comment: @TravisJ - if you set the "forStorage" parameter to true, this will consume credits.  If you are only geocoding to display points on a map, and not store the output data you can set this parameter to false and no credits will be charged.  Here is some [more info on free vs paid operations in the Esri ArcGIS JS API.](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-free-vs-paid.htm). FYI - geocoding consumes [40 credits per 1000 addresses geocoded.](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/credits)

Comment: Thank you. This will help a lot trying to save my customers some money.

Comment: You will have to double check the Esri terms of use, but you can store your geocode results for an extended period of time, then check input addresses against all recently geocached address.  You can use a cached result if available, further saving on credit usage.