# ArcGIS Geocoding Rest API call with c#

Tags: c#, rest, multipartform-data, arcgis

My code was working fine and was from the answer from this link [Formatting RestSharp request for ESRI geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151793/formatting-restsharp-request-for-esri-geocoder)

```
string token = GetToken();
string url="http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses"; 

 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var values = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", token),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("forStorage", "true"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxBatchSize", "1000"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("outFields", "*"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("f", "json"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("addresses", inputJson)  // json string containing an array of a complex type
        };

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)        
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        Task<string> responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string outputJson = await responseString; 
    }
}
```

It seems like ArcGIS needs the URL in encoded format from now on. I have no idea how to encode a API call URL that has multi part form data content using c# code. Please help.

Comment: I would usually use HttpUtility.UrlEncode(...  What is the error, seems odd that there would be any problem with the Url that you are using.  I would expect there is more chance there is an issue with inputJson

Comment: Thanks for the input. PostAsync second parameter is HttpContent type. URL encoding is on string type only. How can we encode the HttpContent which has the key value pairs?